# How to compare values in an array?

Tags: arm

Beginner to ARM here.I have a function called `bubblesort(in, n)` where `in` is an array of integers and `n` is the length of the array.

I am trying to do this `if` condition in ARM:

```c
if (a[j+1] < a[j]) {
    temp = a[j];
    a[j] = a[j+1];
    a[j+1] = temp;
}
```

Here is the ARM code:

```sh
 23         swap:
 24         add r8,r5,#1        // r8 is j + 1
 25         mul r8,r8,#4        // r8 = r8 * 4
 26         add r9,r5           // r9 is j
 27         mul r9,r9,#4        // r9 = r9 * 4
 28         cmp [r0+r8],[r0+r9]
 29         blt switch
```

I get these errors. I think I kind of understand the `mul` one. It is expecting register. What do I do if I am running out of registers? I only have these registers on the Pi. I have used others for other functions.

r0-r3 temp reg (I/O)

r4-r9 storage reg (Global)

r13 Link register

r15 Program counter

> bubble.s:25: Error: ARM register expected -- `mul r8,r8,#4'
>
> bubble.s:27: Error: ARM register expected -- `mul r9,r9,#4'
>
> bubble.s:28: Error: ARM register expected -- `cmp [r0+r8],[r0+r9]'

Comment: As an instruction set reference would tell you, there is no immediate operand form of `mul` - you can only multiply a register by another register. For multiplying by 4, though, you could always just use a shift instead ;)

Comment: @Notlikethat Thanks. I understand that now. What about the comparing values of array elements part? How do I go about doing that?